# localhost:3000 google sign in working but production sign in not working.. redirect mismatch issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, google-signin

[image]

> Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Redirect uri mismatch is one of the most common google oauth error messages.

The redirect uri is used to tell the authorization server where to return the authorization code back to.

This is configured over on google developer console for your project under the credentials themselves.

[image]

The redirect uri your application is sending from **must** exactly match one that you have listed in google cloud console.

If you click on error details it will tell you exactly what redirect uri you need to add in google developer console.

- [Google Oauth: error redirect_uri_mismatch the javascript origin Quick Fix.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0-4LnHwFho)
- [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common mistake that is often overlooked while deploying our applications. You should access your Google Developer console for this project and configure the redirect URL with the deployed URL and few tweaks. Hope this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the redirect URI that is registered with an OAuth client and the one that is being used in the authorization request.

Make sure that the redirect URI you are using in the authorization request is the same as the one that is registered with the OAuth client.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look out for is that the Authorized redirect URIs must not end in a /. If you do this it won't (currently) warn you in the G Cloud interface but it will result in that error.